# Setting up Raspberry Pi and want to install Linux OS

Tags: linux, setup

I just recently discovered Raspberry Pi.

I just want to know, if I want to install Linux on the Raspberry Pi, do I need to download and extract the NOOBS file from a Linux PC? Or Can I just use Windows and then on setting up Raspberry Pi, just choose RASPBIAN?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need OS advice!](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/need-os-advice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to flash the Raspbian image on the SD card. I would recommend using NOOBS if you are new to linux and Raspberry PI

Here is a [tutorial](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_NOOBS). I know links are frowned upon, but there is too much on the tutorial page to repost here

Comment: Ok, I installed Raspbian. Can I install hamachi on Raspbian?

Comment: see http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5207