# I get error while installing Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card

I installed Noobs to my SD card for booting up my RPi but when I select install Raspbian. I get following error after the `erasing EBR` dialog disappears.
[image: Error image]

I installed and formatted my SD card from exfat to FAT.

While installing Raspbian directly without noobs I still get some ugly things on my screen which ends like this
[image]

There was some error -110 during accessing a memory block from SD card.

I am using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HH2H3OK) SD-Card I think it might be causing problem because no operating system could be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would skip NOOBS and go straight to Raspbian.

Download your OS of choice from (including NOOBS, if that is your preference):
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Unzip the file.

Find your SD card:

```
lsblk
```

Then compare the output with the name of your SD-CARD
On Ubuntu:
`df -h`

It will be something like this:

```
disk2
```

Therefore the path to this disk is:

```
/dev/disk2
```

Format your SD card:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 [UNTITLED] MBRFormat /dev/disk#
```

where [UNTITLED] is the name you want to give the disk.

Once the card is formatted, you have to unmount it:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk#
```

On Ubuntu:
`umount <sd-partition-path>`

Then write the image to the disk:

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=/path/to/raspbian.img of=/dev/disk#
```

Insert into Pi and boot!

EDIT:
Based on edited question,

I believe it is your SD card. You need a class 4, yours is a class 10

Comment: Why is noobs not working?

Comment: I don't know, and I doubt @D-W knows either. However, if your goal is to get your Pi up and running, rather than try to figure it out just go ahead and  install raspbian directly.

Comment: I want to install ubuntu-mate  http://www.htpcbeginner.com/run-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-2-ubuntu-mate/ also I just want to know what exactly is that error and what is causing it to occur?

Comment: @Creator the ubuntu-mate install should be no different than these instructions above but downloading a different image. As far as why you are getting this error, I'm not sure without reproducing it myself... But if you want to install ubuntu-mate why does it matter?

Comment: because prior to installing ubuntu mate I wanted to install raspbian.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34636/32640

Comment: @D-W - diskutil is obsolete in my version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Creator See new edits

Comment: It seems that the problem was with SD card which did'nt support any I/O operations from Pi, anyway add the point of checking SD card in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing raspbian directly (and skip NOOBS) by following guide [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: Why should I do that?